# How to verifying whether a file has valid signature in python?

Tags: python, signature, digital

I want to verify signature code in python with the only input is path/to/file

All other sources I've consulted need individual signature files but I only want to take as input a single file (can be .exe or .dll)

I've tried to write code purpose to verify if a file has a valid signature via window powershell

```
def is_valid_Sig(path:str):
    if os.path.exists(path):
        command = f"Get-AuthenticodeSignature \"{path}\"" 
        result = subprocess.run(["powershell.exe", command], capture_output=True)
        result = str(str(result.stdout) + str(result.stderr))
        
        if " Valid " in result:
            return 1
        else: return 0
    else: return -1
```

Is there anyway to do it without using cmd or powershell ?
Please help me, thank  you very much :>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this module called signify [here](https://signify.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: Pls don’t post link-only answers. Pls write a proper answer that actually answers the question.

Comment: Hello, your solution did worked but but there are a few other minor issues
Some file marked as notsigned by the signify module but valid when verifyed by powershell, do you know anyway to fix that

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).